# Android spinner item disappear during scroll

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have created two spinner, but when I add a custom layout to adapter, during scroll some items disappear.

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

java file:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_text, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_text, list2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

How can i resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happens when you are supporting multi languages in you application, where different languages requires different layout direction.

Try adding **android:layoutDirection** to your text view in the custom spinner item layout and this will be fixed.